# How attach event to console app on startup

Tags: c#, reflection

I have application for which I need to add additional hidden logging.

I have put prototype in way.

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");

        new DummyTest().Report();

        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class DummyTest
{
    public void Report()
    {
        var reporter = new Reporter();
        Console.WriteLine("Reporting");
        for (var i =0; i < 155; i++)
        {
            reporter.Process(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Reporting end");
    }
}
public class Reporter
{
    // attach behavior here
    public void Process(int requestId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing request: {0}" , requestId);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Now I have new project logger.dll that contains

```
using System;

namespace logger
{
    public class Log
    {
        public Log()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Line executed");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to execute this method every time Main gets executed. This however cannot be referenced in any other way except only by referencing the dll.

---

=Update=

I do not mind to have reference to that dll. But in main code I cannot have any reference to Log. I thought about using reflection in order to make this work. The problem I am trying to solve first is how to attach that to the execution.

- Why I cannot call logger from main?
- This is supposed to be reporting on usage of the class, monitoring usage, in order to report on performance on bottle necks.

Comment: So you want to execute Log() without referencing logger.dll, right?

Comment: It would be better if you could explain why you can't call `Log` from inside `Main`

Comment: This requires code injection.  Postsharp makes a living doing that.

Comment: @HansPassant is there any way of doing this without Postsharp, I have checked their site, but still hoping

Comment: If you have to ask then you should not be doing this yourself.  IL rewriting is not simple.

Comment: @HansPassant one needs to start somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    System.Console.SetOut(new CustomTextWriter());

    Console.WriteLine("test");
}

public class CustomTextWriter : TextWriter
{
    private TextWriter _consoleOut = null;
    private Log _logger = null;

    public CustomTextWriter()
    {
        _consoleOut = System.Console.Out;
        _logger = new Log();
    }

    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        this.Write(new String(buffer, index, count));
    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        _consoleOut.Write(value);
        _logger.Write(value);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        _consoleOut.WriteLine(value);
        _logger.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.Default; }
    }
}
```

Wasn't sure if you wanted to do logging without actually calling `Console.WriteLine()` (if yes you'll need to look at `Interception`) but if that's ok then this should get you through.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Console.WriteLine()" is just to illustrate the behavior of injection of another logic

Comment: Interception it is then. Lots of info on it but for example you can use this: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception

Answer (score -1):

You could do that with reflection like this:

```
// load the assembly
Assembly LogDll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"Log.dll");

// get the type of the Log class
Type LogType = LogDll.GetType("logger.Log");

// get instance of the Log class
object LogInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(LogType);

// invoke class member "Log()"
LogType.InvokeMember("Log",
                        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | 
                        BindingFlags.Instance | 
                        BindingFlags.Public,
                        null, 
                        LogInstance, 
                        null);
```

Although I'm not sure if the constructor "Log()" already gets called by creating the instance. You should probably move your actual log method out of the constructor. To pass arguments you can use the last parameter of [InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/66btctbe(v=vs.110).aspx) which is an array of the type Object.

Comment: this is nice and I can invoke the implementation from main to log, but what I need it other way around

Comment: You said, you wanted to use the logger.dll from you main project without referencing it directly. In what way do you need it the other way round?

Comment: i mean that i want to have this dll run automatically when main program starts and i do not have to call it from main project

Comment: Okay, so basically you need code injection and function hooking in some way. Enjoy: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/Net-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Codes-on-Run-time